# What is the origin of the phrase "Sharp Showers" in UK Met Office Forecasts

Tags: expressions, terminology, phrase-meaning

The UK Meterological Office is the government body responsible for weather forecasting here.

On TV and radio forecasts, they have taken to using the phrase "sharp showers" to indicate sudden, heavy rain showers (I had to telephone their press office to find that out, as they don't enlarge on it in their limited-time media slots).

But what is the origin of that phrase? I have never heard it used in colloquial British English of any dialect or accent, so wondered where it comes from.

Comment: Perhaps from the phrase "short and sharp" or "short, sharp", meaning brief but intense.

Comment: I have to say that, in 50 years as a meteorologist and forecaster, I've never come across the phrase "sharp showers", but the meaning is pretty obvious and I have no trouble with it.   A sudden strong gust of wind with a short heavy rain shower would usually be called a squall.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase has been in use for over two hundred years.  From [*Transactions of the Dublin Society Volume III for the Year MDCCCII*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O4ZPAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA66&dq=%22sharp%20showers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwADgyahUKEwjDp-mf8LnHAhUENT4KHXtPCww#v=onepage&q=%22sharp%20showers%22&f=false) a description of the weather for September 11, 1802:

> Wind high ; sunshine and a light frost this morning ; a shower of rain
>   and hail about ten ; cloudy and **sharp showers** at intervals this day; a
>   fine clear moonlight night;

Answer (score 0):

**sharp** [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sharp) possible origin

> The adverbial meaning "abruptly" is from 1836;

Though not specifically 'sharp weather' my sense is of abrupt onset.

From Royal Society (Great Britain) - **1749** [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=b8cCAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22sharp%20weather%22&pg=RA2-PA44#v=onepage&q=%22sharp%20weather%22&f=false)

> The Forenoon overcast, with fine fresh Gales at WNW, and **sharp**
>   Weather, the Afternoon more serene and smaller Gales. Q 30 ã 3 26.
>   Fair serene Weather, with fine **sharp** Gales